# Prove that a bipartite graph $G$ always has a matching $M$, such that $|M| \gt \frac{|E(G)|}{∆(G)}$.

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

How can one prove that a bipartite graph $G$ always has a matching $M$, such that $|M| \gt \frac{|E(G)|}{∆(G)}$, where $E(G)$ is the amount of edges and $∆(G)$ is the maximal degree?

Comment: Suppose you have a bipartite graph with all edges incident to the same vertex in one part, so that $|E(G)| = \Delta(G)$ as you've defined it.  Then the maximum matching consists of one edge, but this does not exceed the ratio of $|E(G)|$ to $\Delta(G)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that a bipartite graph G is a union of ∆(G) matchings (maximum degree)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562248/show-that-a-bipartite-graph-g-is-a-union-of-%e2%88%86g-matchings-maximum-degree)